# Spock unrecognized block label: given

Tags: groovy, spock

I have the following spock test.

```
package com.arch.unit.category
import com.arch.domain.category.Category
import com.arch.domain.category.CategoryRepository
import com.arch.handler.category.CategoryCreateHandler
import com.arch.message.command.category.CategoryCreateCommand
import spock.lang.Specification
```

```
def "create category expected succeed"() {
    given:
    def command = new CategoryCreateCommand("Php")
    and:
    categoryRepository.save(_ as Category) >> new Category("Php")
    when:
    def response = handler.execute(command)
    then:
    response.code == 100
}
```

It is not working. I get an error "Error:(20, 16) Groovyc: Unrecognized block label: given"

My dependencies

```
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all')
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-4')
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-4')
```

Environment : Windows, Java8, Intellij Community Edition

It's worked my mac before. But now not working.

Comment: I recommend to edit the question and to also show the class definition + imports. There is possibly something wrong there.

Comment: @kriegaex thank you. I checked but same error. I added imports.

Comment: I actually asked for a full class definition, not for incoherent code snippets. Is it really easier to dissect the class than just to copy it completely? Besides, what did you check? I didn't ask you to check anything. First I need to see your test.